# ipv6 doesn't work until I restart radvd on the firewall

Tags: networking, ipv6, radvd

My laptop (Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS) frequently doesn't get ipv6 routing information until I restart radvd on the linux firewaall.  Then everything works fine.  Any ideas as to how I can get this to work consistantly without manual intervention?

Comment: `sudo radvdump` and `tail -f /var/log/radvd.log` may tell you what's going on. Are you getting an IPv6 address set but no/wrong routing or no IPv6 config at all?

Answer (score 0):

Probably be better to understand how things are breaking, but your question was to restart the service *without manual intervention*; so that's what I'll work with.

Create a systemd service & timer to execute a script which restarts the radvd service.  Copy all the below into a single file onto the Linux GW, `chmod 700` the file and execute it using `sudo`. Obviously change the "24h" to "12h" in the timer part or some other number of hours that suits:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat <<'EOF'> /root/radvd-restart.sh
#!/bin/bash
#
systemctl restart radvd.service
EOF

cat <<EOF> /etc/systemd/system/radvd-restart.service
[Unit]
Description=Restart radvd Service
[Service]
User=root
Group=root
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash /root/radvd-restart.sh
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOF

chmod 644 /etc/systemd/system/radvd-restart.service


cat <<EOF> /etc/systemd/system/radvd-restart.timer
[Unit]
Description=Executes /root/radvd-restart.sh every 24 hours
[Timer]
OnUnitInactiveSec=24h
Unit=radvd-restart.service
[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
EOF

chmod 644 /etc/systemd/system/radvd-restart.timer

systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable radvd-restart.service
systemctl enable radvd-restart.timer
systemctl start radvd-restart.service
systemctl start radvd-restart.timer
```

Again, would be better to understand how things are broken, but this will meet your requirements to stop having to manually kick the service to get it working.